# How to use $_GET variable in blade in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My framework is Laravel 5.2, How to use `{faq}` in blade ?

Route is:

```
Route::get('help/{faq?}', ['as' => 'help', 'uses' => 'Site\Help\IndexController@index']);
```

URL is:

```
http://localhost:8000/help/general
```

I have get `{faq}` in url.

In php, if this url: `http://localhost:8000/help?faq=general` use `$_GET['faq']` But not work `$_GET` in balde in laravel.

please guide me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `request()->route('faq')` or `{{request()->route('faq')}}` in blade

Answer (score 5):

```
Route::get('help/{faq?}', ['as' => 'help', 'uses' => 'Site\Help\IndexController@index']);
```

means that `$faq` is an acceptable argument for `Site\Help\IndexController@index`

So when we look at that

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site\Help;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController {
    public function index(Request $request, $faq) {
        return view('site.help.index', compact('faq'));
    }
}
```

If Faq is not passed as an argument, then you can get it off of the request object.

```
class IndexController {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $faq = $request->has('faq') ? $request->get('faq') : null;
        return view('site.help.index', compact('faq'));
    }
}
```

Now in the view `site.help.index` you can use `$faq.`

Alternatively, you can use - as indicated by @sam, `request->route('faq')` in your view. Make sure you check that it exists however, first:

```
{{ request()->has('faq') ? request()->get('faq') : '' }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, Just Do It `request->route('faq')`.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel blade use `{{request()->get('faq')}}`

Comment: It still works on Laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

Since `faq` an [optional parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), you should do this in `index()` action:

```
public function index($faq = null)
```

Then you can use `$faq` variable and check if parameter does exist with `is_null($faq)`